# Any PHP library that can read PROTECTED Excel Worksheets?

Tags: php, excel

Any PHP libraries for reading Excel files that can read protected .xls worksheets? With and/or without password.

I'm not looking to write to the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect your only option to read a protected workbook from a PHP script is using either the COM extension on a Windows platform, or PUNO on a Linux platform

Comment: Unfortunately we've gone down the path of a macro that loads all workbooks in a specific dir, unlocks them and saves them to another folder. Messy, but it worked.